# Low cost 4-8 port 2.5 GBe switch

Tags: networking, switch

I'm currently specing out my home network, and while going 'full' 10GBe capable is tempting, my options for upgrades are limited. I'm looking at a [Unifi Switch Flex XG](https://store.ui.com/collections/unifi-network-switching/products/unifi-flex-xg) . 2.5GBe is broadly supported and is a coming thing. While switch options for gigabit are plentiful (and I already have a low cost managed gigabit switch)

So here's what I'm looking at

Essentials:

- Low cost. 300USD will get me a 10GBe Switch. I'm half certain I can get a modern unmanaged 1Gbe switch for maybe 20USD. I'm looking to pay ~100USD per 4 ports. At some point a second flex XG would make sense, but I'd rather not be plonking down another 300 USD for a switch that ends up being connected to a 2.5GBps media center box and a tele.
- Compact - Most of the switches in my wishlist or currently in use don't have a ton of 'wasted' space. I don't want a switch that has 5 ports, and  5 ports space worth of panel and blinkenlighten. Being able to fit in the same footprint or slightly bigger than the Flex XG would be nice.
- 2.5Gbe (minimal requirement) or *better* support

Nice to have

- 'Wall' mountability. I have a TPlink TL-SG105 which I've mounted to the side of a desk with screws. The switch has little screw holes

[image]

- Management capability, I can do unmanaged but it would be a nice to have considering some other plans I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **[TRENDnet 5-Port Unmanaged TEG-S350](https://amzn.to/3yWTIaS)** switch seems to be a good option:

- Goes for $129.99
- Wall Mountable; *The 2.5G switches feature metal housing with
  a convenient wall mountable design for greater
  installation flexibility*
- All 5 2.5Gbps Ports
- 109x160x25mm size (smaller than the 135x185x32mm of the UniFi Flex XG)

---

Another option (just to have two...) which is quite similar but somewhat wider (126x209x26mm) is the **[TP-Link TL-SG105-M2](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1637606-REG/tp_link_tl_sg105_m2_5_port_2_5g_desktop_switch.html/specs)**

Comment: the TPlink comes well recommended, and apparently is quite affordable on aliexpress. The trendnet is a new one. While I'm slightly undecided on what to get (my new place got delayed), these options fit all my requirements. The 8 port tplink option seems 'better' value per port from what I've seen

Answer (score 0):

Where I live, the Netgear GS110MX meets all your need to haves, it's under $300 (€190), 8port and 10Gbs. However, it is not managed and probably not wall mountable (My sources do not show a picture of the bottom, but it has feet). It is also bigger than your current switch, but it is not much bigger than it needs to be (it's 8 ports in a row and a few leds on the front)

Comment: It's much bigger, and only 2 ports are 10Gbps (others are Gigabit)

Answer (score 0):

Its 2023 - and there's switches that ticked all my boxes. [The one I got was listed in aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005992916169.html) as the "HORACO 2.5GbE Ethernet Switch 4 Port 2500Mbps Network Switcher 2 Port 10G SFP+ Slot Home Lab Hub Internet Splitter Plug and Play", and the model is ZX-SWTGO24AS. There's an entire class of these switches, but this was at half off, at around 45 USD when I bought it. I went with the 4+2 since much of the rest of my network was 10g capable.

[image]

I'm using the 2 SFP+ cages - one with an off brand DAC and one with a base T module from the same company. Amusingly the SFP+ module cost almost as much as the switch. I've *not* tested all 4 port at once but this class of switch *appears* to handle all 4 ports in other people's testing, and I've tried running speed tests through the 10G ports with good results.

Its also got screw holes, and practically is nearly as small as my old gigabit switch.